# Microsoft Excel 2013 - remove dot in decimal but value zero remain

Tags: excel, decimal

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013

How to remove dot in decimal point but the value after dot will be remain?

Let say I have this value "789.00" . how to convert this value to "78900" ?

Thanks

Comment: multiply it by 100 and format it to drop the decimal?

Comment: how to multiply for each value in each row? sorry noob here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but either way the answer is far more complex than it seems. For one thing, let's assume the value you are working with is a floating point number. (That is to say, for simplicity - a number that can have decimal values). In Excel there are always two things happening on the screen:

1) What you see
2) what is really stored there

Ok so let's say you "see" 1.33. You might think "Hey the decimal place is .33"

But, if you format the cell and choose - "decimal places show 4" you might see this:

1.3333 because in reality, that cell is storing "4/3"

**Decimal precision** is a complex issue in computer science, far beyond the scope of this post - but you can google it for more information. Incidentally, that's why Excel includes a Currency type - it stores values in a way that ensure precision at 2 decimal places.

Anyhow, you could do something like this:
[A1] = 1.3333333 (repeating)

```
A2 = INT(A1*100)
```

The Int function basically strips away the decimal value.. BUT, maybe you want to round because what would you do in this case?

[A1] = 1.5555555 , then maybe it's not so clear what you would be keeping.

(Google the function "round excel" for more information)

If you just want to somehow keep the decimal aspect, and strip away the Integer value you can do this

```
[A1] = 1.25

A2 = A1-INT(A1)
```

*A2 = 0.25*